# Delete Round Rect Buttons with all the references

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4

How to delete Round Rect Buttons on Xcode with all the references. Because if i delete Round Rect Buttons on IBOutlet it will be deleted, but the references and related methods will not be deleted. if i go manual way and delete that methods and references , but it will generate some error on runtime .. is their any way to do it ??

thank you

Comment: how are you creating the buttons? in interface builder or through code?

Comment: What you refer to as references? IBOutlets?

Comment: then if you want to remove the buttons.Delete them in the interface builder.Simple as that. Regarding you method and iboutlets you created in .h & .m files delete them manualy. If problem persists, then first comment those methods and then run your app.I it runs successfully then delete the code.

Comment: @Krishnan : IBAction.. I means after used one of the button like Round Rect Buttons on top of the  UINavigation bar. then all the things are working. but after that if I deleted that button and deleted all the references related to that button like variable and method and All then we cann't ruj it again.. it may appear some error related to that Round Rect Buttons.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is any such short-cut to do that .... you have to go manually ... but I don't think is a tough task If your code is clean

Answer (score 0):

Amit is right you have to do it manually, as in you have to delete all the references yourself.

If you understand how reference counting works and is using it properly this shouldn't be much of a problem. The buttons will not be deleted before all the references are. So the proper way to delete a button is to delete all the references.